# Node.js Express input validation for two strings between a ':' to be accepted

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have implemented a page where students can enter in a their Coursework Name with its intended milestones. However, I want to add validation that will only allow users to enter using the following method, two strings with a ':' between them. For example - 'Coursework : Milestone'. Any length of string accepted, as long as it ensures there are two strings with a ':' to separate them in the middle as seen in the example. I am very new to Node.js, Express, jQuery and Handlebars and I have searched for ways to do this but none seemed useful. Below is the only code needed.

in the controller file, a section for creating a new input data

```
const Task = require('../models/task');


    create: function(req, res) {
        Task
            .create(req.body)
            .then(result => {
                // result.sort(sortTask)
                res.json(result)
            })
            .catch(err => res.json(err));
    }
```

the model file, task.js, for reference

```
//dependency
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//data inputted into the database, coursework/milestones section, validation included
const taskSchema = new Schema({
    task: {
        type: String,
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    addedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
});

const Task = module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

jQuery code to allow these actions to work, in the public folder, eventListeners.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {


//index page events
//click even for creating a milestone/coursework
  $('#create').on('click', function(e) {
      createTask(e);
  });

//keypress event that allows milestone?coursework to be created on 'Enter'
  $('#task').keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          createTask(e);
      }
  });
```

the index.hbs file input section

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Coursework : Milestone" id="task" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is what you're looking for. In your use case:

```
/:/.test(<user input>)
```

Comment: wait sorry I am confused how I would apply this to my code

Comment: If you just want to flag the input string as validated: `var current_input_valid = /:/.test(<user input>)` where <user input> is the input string you've taken from user. Otherwise you use an `if` block: `if ( /:/.test(<user input>) ) { <your code> }`.

Comment: Make sure you're sanitizing input string beforehand. A simple way to achieve that is by replacing any malicious character with a character of your choice. For example: `<user input>.replace(/[\"\']/g, '')`

Comment: it isnt sorry, the explanation doesnt really make sense @chevian